# matlab using the curve of of a histogram as a feature for SVMtrain

Tags: matlab, matrix, histogram, svm

I am trying to include the curvature of a histogram to be used as one of the features in my svmtrain by doing this

```
 [N,edges] = histcounts(img(:,:, 1),15); %quantize to 15bins
 feature21 = hist(N);
```

I understand that in order to perform a svmtrain, I would need to convert all the features into one numeric matrix. However, this features returns a 2x1 graphics array, which I was unable to put it together with my other features when converting to numeric matrix.

Is there any way the above could be done? My aim was to get the curvy-ness of the histogram to be used as a feature, and if I use the values of the histogram instead (15 of them for each image), I would have a lot of additional columns in my numeric matrix, which might override the strength of other features. (I am trying to keep only one value for each feature).

I could use the 1x15 value from my N for my SVM train, but I am trying to maintain only one normalized value for each feature. For example, if I currently have 4 features including the mentioned, my numeric matrix used for the svmtrain would be [feature1 feature2 feature3 feature4_col1 feature4_col2 feature4_col3 ... feature4_col14 feature4_col15] , which in this case, feature 1,2,3 would be assumed as 1 value each for the svmtrain, while feature 4 would be assumed as 15 values for svmtrain (which would make feature 4 more superior over feature 1,2,3)

Comment: Why not use the 1x15 vector `N` as your features?

Comment: @beaker Because I am trying to maintain only one normalized value for each feature. For example, if I currently have 4 features including the mentioned, my numeric matrix used for the svmtrain would be [feature1 feature2 feature3 feature4_col1 feature4_col2 feature4_col3 ... feature4_col14 feature4_col15] , which in this case, feature 1,2,3 would  be assumed as 1 value each for the svmtrain, while feature 4 would be assumed as 15 values for svmtrain (which would make feature 4 more superior over feature 1,2,3)

Comment: Sorry for my messy explanation, I'm kinda new to this and not really sure how to combine everything together.